# mount error(112): Host is down Refer to the mount.cifs(8) manual page (e.g. man mount.cifs) in Raspberry Pi

Tags: samba, raspberrypi, debian, cifs, shared-folders

I tried to mount the sharefolder given by IT team (I think it is the remote folder and  I need to use Win+R to access this folder) in my raspberry pi.

It will be `//100.160.90.89/TempFolder/MyShare`.

I google it and this is my command to mount in raspberry pi.

```
sudo mount.cifs //100.160.90.89/TempFolder/MyShare /home/pi/ShareFile/ -o user=<USER>,password=<PASSWORD>
```

Username and Password is given by IT Team. I didn't use my window USERNAME and PASSWORD.I am not sure if it is correct to use or not.

I have tried with version=1.0 and version=3.0. However, the error still persists.

```
mount error(112): Host is down
Refer to the mount.cifs(8) manual page (e.g. man mount.cifs)
```

Could anyone please suggest me how to figure it out? Thank you.

Comment: The `Host is down` message generally means that the other computer cannot be found on the network. Have you confirmed that everything is up? What operating systems are being used here? You have tagged Debian and mention Windows, but it's unclear ...

Comment: Yeah raspberry pi is in debian, the shared folder I want to mount on pi is inside window os.

Comment: What OS/product/release are you using?

Comment: Please refer https://askubuntu.com/help/on-topic, Ubuntu and official *flavors* of Ubuntu (https://ubuntu.com/download/flavours) are on-topic on this site. The on-topic link provides alternate SE sites for non-Ubuntu OSes.  *You've tagged your question as being about a debian workflow issue, but question doesn't seem to relate to Debian/Ubuntu workflow at all*

Comment: Because my raspberry pi is in debian os so I think it is better to put that also.

Comment: Neither Debian nor Windows are on topic at AskUbuntu, but you may have better luck at [SuperUser](https://superuser.com) 

Comment: Ohh OK OK thank you for the suggestion;.